# Getting more Ruby On Rails Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new on Ruby On Rails and I already watched a long tutorial to start developing a small web application. In such a tutorial I could see several helpers for textboxes, textareas, dates, times, checkboxes, radiobuttons, comboboxes, and so on.

Where can I find other helpers like accordions, WYSIWYG editors (like an HTML editor), and others that can be bound to data from model and used in views? Maybe a toolbox for example.

I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

What you're mostly talking about are [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). There are a bunch of other [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) so I'd recommend reading through them and getting a better idea of what Rails does and can provide.

If you're not finding what you need in that documentation, you may need to add a [3rd party gem](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-install-gems-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip) to your app's `Gemfile`, and follow the gem's documentation for getting it working. [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wysiwyg) is a good place to start searching if you want to see which gems are most common.

And, of course, in the end you might not be able to find something that someone else already wrote and that solves your problem, in which case you will need to write it yourself. For front-end stuff you'll want to get up to speed on how to use HTML, CSS, and Javascript.